# VBS error message - "Line:6, Column:1, Error:(null), Code:800401E4, Source:(null)"

Tags: vbscript, autoit

I'm new to scripting and have stumbled across AutoIt which I want to personally evaluate (along with other scripting technologies).  Does anyone one see any error in this code (I can't determine whether this is a VBS error or someting I don't understand about AutoIt)?

I am using an editor called VbsEdit and I receive an error message as following:
"Line:6, Column:1, Error:(null), Code:800401E4, Source:(null)"

All help appreciated.  TIA

---

```
'Start AutoIt server script first

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "h:\AutoItServer.exe" 

Set oAutoIt = GetObject("AutoIt.Application") ' the magic

WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = &H00CF0000

hGui = oAutoIt.Call("GUICreate", "VBS AutoIt GUI test", -1, -1, -1, -1, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW)
hButton = oAutoIt.Call("GUICtrlCreateButton", "Click", 100, 100, 100, 30)
hButton2 = oAutoIt.Call("GUICtrlCreateButton", "Click me too", 100, 300, 100, 30)

oAutoIt.Call "WinSetOnTop", "VBS AutoIt GUI test", "", 1

AW_FADE_IN  = &H00080000
oAutoIt.Call "DllCall", "user32.dll", "bool", "AnimateWindow", "hwnd", hGui, "dword", 1000, "dword", AW_FADE_IN

oAutoIt.Call "GUISetState"

Do
    Select Case oAutoIt.Call("GUIGetMsg")
        Case -3
            Exit Do
        Case hButton
            oAutoIt.Call "MsgBox", 262144+32+3, "Title", "Bzzz bzz bzzzz", 0, hGUI
        Case hButton2
            oAutoIt.Call "Beep", 500, 700
    End Select
    Wscript.Sleep(10)
Loop

oAutoIt.Call "GUIDelete"

If oAutoIt.Call("MsgBox", 4 + 48 + 262144, "?", "Kill server?") = 6 Then oAutoIt.Quit
```

Comment: @Mr47: The edit summary is enough to describe your edit. You don't need to put it in the content again.

Comment: It looks like you are using the example from [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/128627-access-autoit/). I'd post in that thread rather than here as it's a pretty specific problem and the AutoIt community is small/non-existant on stackoverflow.

Comment: Try running it on a local disc such as C: instead of a (probably) network or external disc H:

Comment: First-thank you for your comments.  Manadar, I moved the AutoItServer.exe to the C drive and it still bombs out in the same place with the same error code

Comment: No, AutomatedChaos,  that doesn't resolve it either.  The AutoItserver.exe opens successfully but then the script doesn't continue, it waits at line 6.  If you wait minutes and then close the server exe the script continues and bombs out in the same way previously

Comment: Answered by trancexx of AutoIt forum Example scripts (the producer of the AutoItServer, which provides a way to use AutoIt functionality from other script languages...) see: 

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/128627-access-autoit/page__st__20

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to Get the object before it is initialized completely. (at the line where the magic happens)

Try `WshShell.Run "h:\AutoItServer.exe", 1, true` this makes the script wait until the autoitserver is started.

Comment: Answered by trancexx of AutoIt forum Example scripts (the producer of the AutoItServer, which provides a way to use AutoIt functionality from other script languages...) see: 

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/128627-access-autoit/page__st__20